# Don't see number of usages in inlay hints

Tags: pycharm, inlay-hints

In Pycharm, I'd like to see the number of times each function and method in my code are used. I thought this was the use of *inlay hints -> code vision -> usages*, which I have turned on...

[image: Inlay Hints settings]

However, these usages are not showing up in my code. In the example below, if I right-click and choose *find usages* I see that this method is called 54 times...

[image: method that is called 54 times]

Am I doing something wrong? Is there something else I need to set? Am I misinterpreting how to use this functionality?

Comment: What PyCharm version is this? I'm on an older version and don't have the `Code Vision` list in the `Inlay Hints`. Without the new inlay hints, using `find usages` would give the count and kind of usages an object has in the search window.

Comment: I just upgraded over the weekend so I'm on the latest... 2023.1 (Professional Edition) Build #PY-231.8109.197, built on March 29, 2023. I can use find usages but, sometimes, it would be nice to just see the number of usages while looking at a function.